# How do I disable cursor shadow?

Tags: cursor

Is it possible to disable the cursor shadow in Ubuntu 13.10? The shadow is ruining my cursor theme's glow effect.

Comment: I know how to change cursor theme. But what I want to do is to disable shadow. In windows I saw the same theme looking better without shadows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try this way.

Open your terminal and run this command:

```
echo "Xcursor.core: 1" >> ~/.Xresources
```

Then log out and back in.

If you want your cursor shadow back, you need to remove the file and restart the Xserver.

Comment: happy to have helped you! :)